Monitoring and checking clients' connection to the server in C#
I am working in the field of Internet of Things, and I have encountered a challenge. I want to monitor the status (connected/disconnected) of a list of devices (clients) that are connected to the server via port 9090. Please assist.
Thanks.
    TcpListener listener;
    Thread listenThread;


    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        try
        {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.Stop();
            listener.Start();
            listBoxClients.Invoke(new Action(() => listBoxClients.Items.Add("Listening for clients...")));

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                string clientAddress = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                listBoxClients.Invoke(new Action(() => listBoxClients.Items.Add($"Client connected: {clientAddress}")));

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CheckClientConnection), client);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void CheckClientConnection(object clientObject)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)clientObject;
        string clientAddress = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

        while (client.Connected)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1 second before checking again
        }

        listBoxClients.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            listBoxClients.Items.Remove($"Client connected: {clientAddress}");
            listBoxEvents.Items.Add($"Client disconnected: {clientAddress}");
        }));
    }


    private void Listening()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(txtPort.Text));
        listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        listenThread.Start();
    }


Are you sure you want to use raw TCP for IoT devices? MQTT was specifically designed for IoT, and should make things like listing devices much easier.
